# The while() loop is executing infinitely

Tags: c

I had a problem where  have to print ASCII values of characters from 1 to 255 so I wrote this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    while (a<=123)
    {
        printf("the ascii value of %c is %d\n",a,a);
        a++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs fine and prints the ASCII values till I think (a<=130) too but when I put the condition like while(a<=150) or while(a<=255)
it keeps executing infinitely. What may be the reason it is happening?

I was expecting that all the values will be printed.

Comment: `char` seems to be signed on your machine, which means it can only yield values between  -128 and 127 inclusively. you might try `unsigned char`

Comment: i dont think the problem is unsigned char because i just edited and it still does the same thing

Comment: So two tings: make your char unsigned and initialize it to 0.

Comment: i just did unsigned and initialized to 0 and put the condtion (a<=254)and it worked ,one more thing are there only 1-254 ascii values?

Comment: If you are running on an embedded system you had to prevent your program to start again after finishing the `while`loop.

Comment: ASCII codes range from 0 to 127 inclusively. Whoever tells you otherwise lies.

Comment: Your modification of the code in your question makes it completely different. You should not change the code significantly after answers were given.

Comment: @akshat.1010 "ASCII values of characters from 1 to 255" --> [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only defined [0 to 127].  Just drop _ASCII_ form the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `char` is signed or unsigned on any given platform is implementation-defined. A signed `char` would overflow at `a == 127` (which would be undefined behavior), so `a <= 150` can never become false.

`a <= 255` can never become false regardless of the signedness of `char`. (Assuming 8-bit chars.)

Comment: so whats the solution i mean should i just leave it at 127

Comment: @akshat.1010 change it to `a < 255` and separately print `255` afterwards.

Comment: You can also use a wider type like `int` and cast it to `char` before using.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya reason for this a<255 ??

Comment: @akshat.1010 if char uses 8 bits, it can never hold the value 256. So the condition `a <= 255` will always be true. `a < 255` on the other hand will be false when a = 255 (the maximum value representable by char

Comment: @akshat.1010 An even cleaner solution than what Ajay suggested, without using "magic numbers", would be to include `<limits.h>` and loop from `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX`. You would need a wider type for that, too, or you would end up with an infinite loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid needlessly obscure loops and all problems will go away. Always use the idiomatic `for` loop form `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` when you can - especially whenever the number of iterations is known.

```c
a=1;
for(int i=0; i<256; i++) 
{ 
  printf("the ascii value of %c is %d\n", a+i, a+i); 
}
```

Comment: actually my teacher is teaching me while loops and i just started but thanks for the answer .. i'll look it up once i come to for loops

Answer (score 1):

`a` is type `char`.  When `a == CHAR_MAX` (and `a` is *signed*), `a++` is undefined behavior (UB) and smart compilers may take advantage of that in surprising ways.

Instead, use `CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX` from `<limits.h>` to cover the entire `char` range.

---

The following works for all `char`, be it a *unsigned* or *signed* `char`, 2's complement or not, 8, 9, ... or even 64-bit `char`.

```
char a = CHAR_MIN;
for (;;) {
  printf("the value of '%c' is %d\n", a, a);
  if (a == CHAR_MAX) {
    break;
  }
  a++;
}
```

Pedantic: for exceptional systems with a wide `char` and `char` is *unsigned*, use `%u` instead of `%d`.

---

For [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values, which are a sub-set of possible character values, iterate 0 to 127. Code could use `unsigned char` in this case.

```
#define ASCII_MAX 127
for (unsigned char a = 0; a <= ASCII_MAX; a++) {
  printf("the ASCII value of '%c' is %u\n", a, a);
}
```

---

- `char a; while (a<=123)` itself is a problem as `a<=123` attempts to read the uninitialized/unassigned `a`.
  Tip: Save time. Enable all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

> The code runs fine and prints the ASCII values till I think (a<=130) too but when I put the condition like while(a<=150) or while(a<=255) it keeps executing infinitely. What may be the reason it is happening?

The problem is that, when your `char` value reaches its maximum value (probably +127) it overflows on incrementing, resulting in an Undefined Behaviour.  The most probable reason is your compiler using `signed char` as default `char` type.  The values of this type extend from -128 to +127 in the majority of today implementations.  This probably will work upto 127, but not for 128 and above